# Structs and functions

Tags: c, function, struct

I've declared a struct like this.

```
typedef struct fileProperties //the struct.
{
    char name[256]; /*File or directory name*/ 
    int mode;   /*protection and file type*/ 
    int userId; /*User ID of owner*/
    int groupId;    /*Group ID of owner*/
    int size;   /*file size in bytes*/
    char modifyTime[50];    /*modify time as a string*/
} FILES;
```

I would like to write to the properties of file1, in a function call like this.

```
int createStruct()
{
    char structBuffer[251];
    printf("\n > Please enter a file name to create a struct for.> ");
    inputFix(structBuffer, STRUCT_SIZE);
    strncpy(file1.name, structBuffer, sizeof(structBuffer));
    printf(" > Created.");
    return 0;
}
```

Where inputFix is:

```
void inputFix(char string[],int length)
{
    int ch, len = 0;
    fgets(string, length, stdin);
    string[strcspn(string, "\r\n")] = '\0';
    len = strlen(string);
    if (len == length - 1)
    {
        while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    }
}
```

STRUCT_SIZE is defined as a size of 250.

At the top of my code I have this statement.

```
FILES file1;
```

I have read a couple of tutorials from coding unit and tutorials point in relation to structs.

I can't see why i get an error:

```
functions.c:59:3: error: unknown type name ‘FILES’
functions.c:62:52: error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union
```

Is it not worth using typedef? Am I missing something in relation to using structs, if so a link to another similar question would be appreciated.

It might be relevant that this program is split into 2 files main.c functions. c & .h. Do I need to include the struct in the linker file? the main.c only calls createStruct().

Comment: Do you have the `#include` line before the `FILES file1;` line?

Comment: well, **At the top of my code** -- do you mean the line `FILES file1` before the define of `struct`?

Comment: The `typedef` should be in the `.h` file. The `#include` line for the `.h` file has to be before you declare the structure.

Comment: after the #includes I have FILES file1.

Comment: Your code just compiled fine for me. Not sure where you have declared 'fileProperties'. I declared all in '.c' file.  "At the top of my code I have this statement.". Could that be a problem? Above where you typedef'd fileProperties?

Comment: I've just moved some of the declarations around based on one of the answers. Got a little confused with having 2 .c files. It appears to compile fine now.

Comment: The third argument to `strncpy` is supposed to be the size of the destination buffer. In this case, `sizeof file1.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the definition of variable `FILE file1` is in `main.c` while function `createStruct` in file `functions.c`. In such case, you need to put:

```
extern FILES file1;
```

into your hedaer file and to include it at the beginning of `functions.c`. Otherwise the compiler does not know that there is the variable `file1` defined in another file.

So your `header.h` will look like this:

```
typedef struct fileProperties //the struct.
{
  char name[256]; /*File or directory name*/ 
  int mode;   /*protection and file type*/ 
  int userId; /*User ID of owner*/
  int groupId;    /*Group ID of owner*/
  int size;   /*file size in bytes*/
  char modifyTime[50];    /*modify time as a string*/
} FILES;

extern FILES file1;
```

Your `main.c` will look like:

```
#include "header.h"

FILES file1;

...
```

and your `functions.c` will look like

```
#include "header.h"

int createStruct()
{
    ...
    strncpy(file1.name, structBuffer, sizeof(structBuffer));
...
```

Comment: This is only needed if he has multiple object files that he's linking together.

Comment: FILE files1 is declared in functions.c and .h, createStruct() is in functions.c

Comment: You need to define the structure in the header file and before the `extern FILES file1`. Each C file is compiled in a single compiler pass, so when reading file from beginning to the end, everything required at a given point must be declared before this point.